# How to jump directly on page no using text box in jquery book block?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using bookblock template (http://tympanus.net/Development/BookBlock/index2.html.
Here is no pageno search facilty.Can anyone please tell me how to use search page no function for this.
Here is little code :

```
<div class="main clearfix">
                <div class="bb-custom-wrapper">
                    <div id="bb-bookblock" class="bb-bookblock">
                        <div class="bb-item" id="1">
                            <img class="bb-custom-img" src="images/demo2/1.jpg" alt="image01" />
                            <audio src="img/004_Joduniya Kar Charni_128kbps.mp3" controls="">
<p>If you are reading this, it is because your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
</audio>
                        </div>
    <div class="bb-item" id="2">
                            <img class="bb-custom-img" src="images/demo2/1.jpg" alt="image01" />
                            <audio src="img/004_Joduniya Kar Charni_128kbps.mp3" controls="">
<p>If you are reading this, it is because your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
</audio>
                        </div></div></div>
```

Comment: I think that you have two questions. I suggest you to split in two questions and delete this one.

Comment: @angelcervera : I edited